# MySQL-Workbench Connection Fail

Tags: mysql-workbench

Try to ask a question because the DB connection in MySQL Workbench continues to fail.
Enter connection information and Test Connection was successful.

However if i select the appropriate DB Connection in workbench home, the connection success window does not appear.

```
local DB : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.14-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision ab7b9cf9122f6eb02744082db8672a920ae6009f

Server DB : mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.14-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision ab7b9cf9122f6eb02744082db8672a920ae6009f

MySQL Workbench Version : mysql-workbench-community-8.0.16-winx64
```

The same error occurs even if the version of Workbench is changed to 19 or 20.

How to solve it?

[Manage Server Connections - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acPy2.png)

[MySQL Workbench - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk7oK.png)

------More details---------

If you check the log file in the top Help tab of Workbench, you can see the log as below.

```
11:23:15 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Opened connection 'DB Name' to mariadb.org binary distribution version 10.3.14-MariaDB
11:23:15 [ERR][      WBContext]: Unsupported server version: mariadb.org binary distribution 10.3.14-MariaDB
```

However, the connection is normally established on the other coworker's PC.

Comment: You said the same error occurs regardless of workbench version. What error occurs?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson No separate error window is displayed and the connection window blinks and disappears as shown in the second picture.

Comment: You mean you get the Opening SQL Editor message, but the SQL Editor window never appears as a separate tab in Workbench?

Comment: Yes. As in the second picture, the connection window turns off and you return to your home. @HoneyboyWilson

Comment: I've never had that happen. Once I create a connection and it passes the Test Connection feature, clicking the connection on the home tab always takes me to the SQL Editor tab.

Answer (score -1):

Just also encountered the same issue and I already resolved it. I tried using other software application like Navicat and the connection is always succuessful. Perhaps the issue is within the workbench itself so what I did was I uninstalled the workbench and clear the data of the workbench to remove any intentional and unintentional configurations.

By clearing the data, I deleted the files of workbench from Program Files and AppData

After that, I installed the workbench again and input the connection details and the issue was gone. Hope this helps!

Note: Installing Navicat is not a necessary step. It just confirms my theory that the issue is within the workbench and not on the connection or server